# Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier, (ajax for django)

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to correct the error the console is talking about can anyone help me ? 
This is the just a pop up with list of error if the email isn't good.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input#id_st-courriel").focusout(checkEmailField);
    });
function checkEmailField(){
    $fieldValue = $("input#id_st-courriel").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/ajax/checkEmailField',
        data: ({value : $fieldValue}),
        type: 'GET', 5
        success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
            if ($data != ''){
                alert($data);
            }
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

The console tell me an error at this line but i don't know why :

```
success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Error should be in this line

```
type: 'GET', 5
```

what is `5` here? Remove it from there and then test it.

```
function checkEmailField() {

    $fieldValue = $("input#id_st-courriel").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/checkEmailField',
        data: ({
            value: $fieldValue
        }),
        type: 'GET',
        success: function($data, $textStatus, $XMLHttpRequest) {
            if ($data != '') {
                alert($data);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: i have delete '5' but nothing change

Comment: Thanks you so much Sachin for your correct code ! It's work !